# Java gridbaglayout using scrollpane with draggable jpanel

Tags: java, swing, draggable, gridbaglayout

Im using a gridbaglayout on a jpanel with a scrollpane, all that works fine. Later in my code i add another jpanel using the constraints(x,y) to the same panel on top of everything else thats already there using the index, this also works fine. This added jpanel uses a listener to let me drag the panel around which also works but my problem is when i scroll or resize the jframe it puts the jpanel back where it was before i dragged it. Why?

Answer (score 2):

> This added jpanel uses a listener to let me drag the panel around which also works but my problem is when i scroll or resize the jframe it puts the jpanel back where it was before i dragged it. Why?

Because you are using a layout manager. When the frame is resized the layout manager is invoked and components are assigned a size/location based on the rules of the layout manager.

Check out the [Drag Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/). It will allow you to drag components around a panel without resetting the location of the components.

Comment: Ill look into that but that would be bad if i have to redo everything because of this lol. I thought i had it all figured out until i got to this part, thanks.